# Why is my logo not showing up?

Tags: html, image

I'm sure this is super easy but I'm a beginner.  I have my code to pull up my logo but my logo just pulls up a broken image icon.  See screencast

**See screencast:** http://screencast.com/t/ar8cpTIbMs

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
<img  src="C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Website Development"/>
</div>
```

I really only need my HTML figured out and I assume the CSS will work pretty well after that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you should link it to your image file. not only directory. for example, `<img  src="C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Website Development\logo.jpg"/>`

Comment: Don't use absolute paths in your `src` attribute, use a relative. Where is the image in relation to your HTML file. Take a read of this to learn more about paths: http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: You need to be aware that such pathnames will not work on the internet, assuming this will wind up there. The internet was created on Unix and mostly runs on Unix so, first, your slashes are going the wrong way and, second, spaces must be url encoded; something you need to look into. Also, img tags don't have a closing slash, though it's not invalid, it's pointless and useless to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the correct file name for src. Such as

```
<img src="C:\path\to\your\file.jpg" />
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Please note that it is not a good practice to use absolute paths in your src attribute.

In the other hand, you can use base64 encoded image data as src of your img tag. Something like

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...//Z" />
```

https://www.base64-image.de/tutorial

If you use this method, you dont need to keep your logo.jpg file anywhere.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to a directory in your img tag, instead of an image file. Also, I would suggest either practicing online in a free webhost or downloading a stack package like WAMP/MAMP/LAMP. You'll start running into problems where you can use http protocols pretty quickly in your studies. Though, that can get technical, so I say stick to a free webhost for now. You will get weird hang ups trying to use the file system that will ultimately confuse you while you are trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `src` for your `<img>`. You're linking it to a directory `/Users/Brent/Documents/Website Development` right now, when you should be linking it to the image. If your image is called logo.png, then you should link it with `C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Website Development\logo.png`. Also, instead of linking it to `C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Website Development\logo.png`, link it to the image based on where the file is. For example, if your file is in `\Website Development\index.html`, then all you need to put for the `src` is `"logo.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

please enter the complete path including your image.
for example if your file name is mypic.jpg .Then

```html
<img src="C:\Users\Brent\Documents\Website Development\mypic.jpg" />
```

Comment: Your markup is invalid. The img element has no closing tag.

Comment: Your markup is still invalid. You don't close the quote and the img tag, though not invalid, does not have a closing slash.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your logo to the same path as your website. Ex:

> Website: C:/site/index.html
>
> Logo: C:/site/logo.jpg

Then include the logo as:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img src="logo.jpg">
</div>
```

Hint: You don't have to have the div for the logo to show up.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. The img element does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Because browsers are required to fix bad markup to the best of their ability. If you wish to let browsers guess at your intentions, that's up to you, but I prefer to write proper markup in the way it is intended in the specification and not be embarrassed when others see what I wrote.

Comment: @Rob Okay, thank you for correcting this. I will fix it straight away.

Comment: As another note, the img tag does not have a closing slash. It's not invalid to do so but browsers are instructed by the specification to ignore the slash because it has no meaning and has no function which makes its usage pointless in HTML.

Comment: @Rob Okay I will fix that as well. "The more you know!"